# How do I install a pip python fused_kernels library on a GPU CUDA machine?

Tags: python, pip, gpu, nvidia

https://github.com/EleutherAI/gpt-neox/blob/5dd366539803dbf1fd725cc057013fd002a4cfd4/requirements.txt#L28

```
fused-kernels @ file:///fsx/hailey/math-lm/gpt-neox/megatron/fused_kernels
```

Line 28 here is different from all the others, it's saying use the local file system to find `fused_kernels`. But I'm missing it:

```
No such file or directory: '/fsx/hailey/math-lm/gpt-neox/megatron/fused_kernels
```

Update: I ran

```
python ./megatron/fused_kernels/setup.py install
```

first and it said it worked but still the problem remains.

How do I solve this chicken egg situation? I need it installed before I can install it?

Comment: Read the [readme](https://github.com/EleutherAI/gpt-neox/tree/5dd366539803dbf1fd725cc057013fd002a4cfd4#set-up-environment): `python ./megatron/fused_kernels/setup.py install`

Comment: I did this. It worked or said success but still the directory is missing.

Comment: The path in the `requirements.txt` looks like an absolute path. Have you tried substituting the corresponding path on your system?

Comment: thank you paleonix, i posted my silly mistake as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally understand what I was doing wrong.

`/fsx/hailey/` is just the path from some dude's machine and it's not magical. I kept assuming something would create that directory and install something there. But I'm needed to edit the requirements.txt file and replace /fsx/hailey/ with /home/me etc. duh. Thank you paleonix for comment.